# Hide mouse cursor on whole screen in Java

Tags: java, mouse, screen

How can I hide the mouse cursor on whole screen in Java?
I used the transparent gif techinique, but it only works on the JFrame area. I need it to work outside the JFrame bounds.

Comment: more suggestions here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191592/how-do-i-get-rid-of-the-mouse-cursor-in-full-screen-exclusive-mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use [transperent GIF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191592/how-do-i-get-rid-of-the-mouse-cursor-in-full-screen-exclusive-mode) and another is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1984071/how-to-hide-cursor)

Comment: Take a full screened JFrame and make visible only that part which is required.

Answer (score 0):

I think an application that can hide the cursor for itself and any other application running on the same desktop is, well, not desirable for usability and maybe security implications. Therefore I guess the win32 API has numerous ways to do it. Even by accident. But (un?)fortunately Java has no API to accomplish this.

Possibly the [Robot](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) is of help for you. You could create a full-sceen capture which gets displayed in turn by an full-screen `JFrame` which in turn has no visible pointer.

Comment: no offense, but i would vote this down if i had a bit more reputation...there are plenty of use cases (e.g. art and museum installations) in which interaction with the content is achieved through non-mouse+keyboard interfaces, and a mouse cursor can be distracting or misleading.

Comment: But such an installation would likely be implemented as an full-screen application, which can hide it's mouse cursor as it likes. My main point was that it seems a bad idea if one application was able to hide the mouse cursor globally (or for any other application).